# grub rescue with all partition as unknown filesystem

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, grub

I accidentally shred all my partitions by:

```
shred -vfz -n 3 /dev/sd?
```

Now I have only grub in rescue mode.

```
error: no such partition.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)
greub rescue> ls (hd0)
(hd0): Filesystem is unknown.
```

The filesystem is also unknown to all the partitions. I am trying to install a Ubuntu on top of it. I do not care about those data and I was attempting to remove them.

I tried placing bootable USB with Ubuntu 18.04 / disk repairer. The USB is recognized as (hd1) but it does not boot.

I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Suggestion towards what goal? Shred it better? Install a clean Ubuntu? Recover old data? How exactly did you shred the partitions? Please [edit] the question.

Comment: Hope this helps make my post clearer

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I decided to switch a new harddrive. After installing a new harddrive and Windows, the laptop works properly.